# Backchannel SignOut using IdentyServer4 and Asp.net Core 2.0 example?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am able to successfully use the Front Channel sign out with IdentityServer4 and Asp.net Core 2.0. Easy enough setting up the FrontChannelLogoutUri for the Client (in IDS4) and pointing it at the ".../signout-oidc" URI. As I understand it, the signout-oidc URI is provided by the Authentication code in Asp.net Core 2.0.

Does anyone have a working example of how the Back channel sign out would be used instead? I see the IDS4 client settings have a BackChannelLogoutUri option, but which URI should it point to? I also see the OpenIdConnect middleware in Asp.net Core 2.0 has some optiojns for backchannel. Do I need to set those up?

I haven't been able to find any sample code on IDS4 GitHub repo or even Microsoft's aspnet GitHub repo.

Any help, especially a working example in a GitHub repo, would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!.

Comment: Quick update: found the talk by Brock and Dominick at NDC London 2018 [link](https://vimeo.com/254635632) that mentions that this is not implemented in Asp.net Core 2.0 and has to be implemented manually in your own "Logout" controller action. You can sort of see what they did in the video, but still having a working example in a GitHub repo would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is here on [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1712).
No plans for this in Asp.net Core 2.0 or 2.1.